# strange matplotlib resizing behavior

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyqt4

I'm embedding matplotlib in my PyQt 4 application and using it to display images. The matplotlib control is being displayed in a QDockWidget, and I'm setting some its parameters as follows:

```
imagePlot = self.axes.imshow(myNumpyArray, interpolation = "nearest")
imagePlot.axes.set_axis_off()
imagePlot.axes.get_xaxis().set_visible(False)
imagePlot.axes.get_yaxis().set_visible(False)
self.fig.subplots_adjust(bottom = 0, top = 1, left = 0, right = 1)
```

This has the desired effect i.e. the image is displayed filling as much space as possible in the QDockWidget while maintaining the aspect ratio. I can resize the dock widget by shrinking it horizontally and then expanding it and the image display is correct (filling as much space as possible while maintaining the aspect ratio). Now, if I add the following line:

```
imagePlot.axes.set(adjustable = "datalim")
```

I get unexpected behavior. Initially the image is displayed in the same manner as before, but after shrinking and expanding horizontally matplotlib seems to introduce a border around the data. For example, here's the image as it is displayed initially (and correctly):

[image: Before size manipulation]

And here's what matplotlib displays after I drag the side of the containing dock widget and shrink, then expand back to original size. Note the appearance of the border around the image.

[image]

What is causing this and how can I prevent it? Thank you.

Comment: If it's working just fine without setting `adjustable = "datalim"`, why to you include it and not leave it out?

Comment: I'm sorry, I omitted that bit...I'm zooming in by setting the xlim and ylim and I need to make use of all the space available. If I don't specify "adjustable = datalim" then the plot only draws in the initial area (I would be zooming in but still have the padding on the left and right hand side of the plot).