# matplotlib FigureCanvasTkAgg window shakes when in zoom or pan mode

Tags: python, matplotlib

Have a problem. 
My plot in the FigureCanvasTkAgg 'jumps', when the NavigationToolbar2Tk is in the zoom or pan mode AND when the mouse crosses either of the axes. Very irritating((

I'm attaching a [Gif image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hdEXG.gif) and an equivalent [youtube link](https://youtu.be/jkEs91HjzcU).

Also attaching the code to one of the three graphs.

```
# ______________frCum
    self.frCum = Frame(self.frGraph)
    self.frCum.grid(row=4, sticky='nswe')
    self.frCum.configure(relief=GROOVE)
    self.frCum.configure(borderwidth="2")
    self.frCum.configure(relief=GROOVE)
    self.frCum.configure(background="#d9d9d9")
    self.frCum.configure(highlightbackground="#d9d9d9")
    self.frCum.configure(highlightcolor="black")
    self.frCum.configure(height=10)

    try:
        if g_graph_settings.pdp_kde_hist == 0:
            graph_to_draw = g_grainset.ckde(g_graph_settings.bandwidth)

        elif g_graph_settings.pdp_kde_hist == 1:
            graph_to_draw = g_grainset.cpdp()
    except NameError:
        pass

    self.fig = Figure(figsize=(6, 2.15), frameon=False)
    self.ax_cum = self.fig.add_subplot(111)
    self.ax_cum.set_title('Cumulative diagrams')
    self.ax_cum.axes.get_yaxis().set_visible(False)

    try:
        self.ax_cum.plot(list(range(0, EarthAge)), graph_to_draw)
    except UnboundLocalError:
        pass

    self.canvas_cum = FigureCanvasTkAgg(self.fig, self.frCum)
    self.canvas_cum.draw()
    self.canvas_cum.get_tk_widget().pack(side='top', fill='both', expand=1)

    self.frCumToolbar = Frame(self.frGraph)
    self.frCumToolbar.grid(row=5, sticky='ew')
    self.frCumToolbar.configure(relief=GROOVE)
    self.frCumToolbar.configure(borderwidth="2")
    self.frCumToolbar.configure(relief=GROOVE)
    self.frCumToolbar.configure(background="#d9d9d9")
    self.frCumToolbar.configure(highlightbackground="#d9d9d9")
    self.frCumToolbar.configure(highlightcolor="black")
    self.frCumToolbar.configure(width=200)
```

Comment: Found the solution in here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45086680/strange-matplotlib-resizing-behavior

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact problem you describe. For me what fixed it was running the program from the shell rather than spyder. I still do not know why it shakes in spyder.

Comment: Thanks, but running from the cmd didn't have any effect. Executable file made by pyinstaller also has the shaking.